# Debian 9, running script at shutdown

Tags: debian

This is driving me insane. Been testing now for two days. What used to work fine on Debian 7 now won't do anymore on Debian 9.

Just a normal Debian 9 from scratch, so nothing special.

I want my backup script called *mybackup.sh* to run on shutdown. This script moves folders and files into a remote tar file and also backups mysql tables to a remote host.

I placed the file (as with Debian 7) in /ect/init.d/

When executed directly it works fine.

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/mybackup.sh    
sudo /etc/init.d/mybackup.sh
```

All backups run like they should, it only takes about a maximum of 20 Seconds.

On Debian 7 I simply put a symbolic link in */etc/rc0.d* to let it run on shutdown.

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/mybackup.sh /etc/rc0.d/K04mybackup.sh
```

This used to work without any problems. The backup files had been generated on the remote folders and hosts and then the machine shut down smooth.

But this fails on Debian 9.

I tried the following

- command *update-rc.d* to manipulate header information
- and/or renaming link to K00…, S00…, K04…, S04…
- generating services which "should" start a script one shutdown

Nothing worked. Simply nothing happens. I can't even find any warning or error messages during shutdown or in log files.

I don't get it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Debian has changed it's init system to `systemd` starting from Debian8

Comment: S**t. But why are all those folders and files (dozens!) still existing?

Comment: have you upgraded the system from an earlier version?

Comment: No, as I wrote *from scratch*. Those folders are still (again) there. They got README files inside but non of them telling that those stuff is obsolete now. Crap. I think I will switch to devuan

Comment: I like Gentoo's openrc

Answer (score 1):

Try will following steps, hope it will solve your issue

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/mybackup.sh /etc/systemd/system/mybackup.service

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable mybackup.service
systemctl start mybackup.service
```